# Fade reveal text from bottom of line break. CSS / JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, heading

So, I need to achieve a really nice fade reveal text effect. Imagine a H1 that's spread across two lines. The text would need to reveal up from the base of each line. However I'm unsure of how to do this with multi-lined text (that isn't split into separate heading tags).

Here's one I created already, however this fades everything from the bottom. Ideally I want each line to fade up from its own row.

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.ready').addClass('active');
}, 1500);
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
  padding:0;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.ready {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

.active {
  opacity:1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.reveal-in {
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-hidden iv-wp">
    <h1 class="ready reveal-in">
      This is text over two lines, with a really nice fade effect.
    </h1>
</div>
```

Similar to this reference -

https://basicagency.com/

Thanks guys.

Comment: It’s probably not the worst question title of all time ... but you’re quite close. Please go read [ask] in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe, edited the question title. I am trying to achieve the best possible fade reveal of all time though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.ready').addClass('active');
}, 1500);
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
  padding:0;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.ready {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

.active {
  opacity:1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.reveal-in {
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
}
.reveal-in2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-hidden iv-wp">
    <h1 >
      <span class="ready reveal-in">This is text over two lines, with</span>
      <span class="ready reveal-in2"> a really nice fade effect.</span>
      
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/x5fgnbpx/1/

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.ready').slideDown("slow");
}, 1500);
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}

h1 {
  padding:0;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.ready {
  opacity:1;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-hidden iv-wp">
    <h1 class="ready reveal-in">
      This is text over two lines, with a really nice fade effect.
    </h1>
</div>
```

To achieve the same, I've used `jQuery slideDown`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) which is quite easy to use. You can check the demo [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

All you need to do is to add a class name which is `animated` and your choice of animation which can be found on the link provided. You can choose `slideInDown` or `slideInUp` or more. Check and play with the demo link that I have provided.

Added a [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3j76952/)